# Issue with :global() css-module selectors not being pure in NextJS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, css-modules

So I'm migrating an app from CRA to NextJS and I have encountered an error for the .module.scss files of some components and pages:

```
Syntax error: Selector ":global(.label-primary)" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)
```

I get this error for all the :global and :local css-module selectors. Based on what I have searched I can fix this issue by wrapping the selector in a class and editing the jsx aswell. but wouldn't that defeat it's purpose?
And how is this working on the CRA version of the app and not on NextJS?

EDIT:
One solution I have for this is moving :global() selectors to the global css files that are imported in _app.js but my question is that is there any way that we can have so these styles would be usable like they are right now ( :global(...) )?

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to move these to the global scss files then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't any solution as of yet other than overriding the webpack config itself. It was working in CRA because they probably have [`mode`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#mode): `local`, while Next.js has [`pure`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/0af3b526408bae26d6b3f8cab75c4229998bf7cb/packages/next/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/loaders/modules.ts#L44).

---

I haven't tried overriding `css-loader` webpack config, so I am simply suggesting a workaround. Since, you are using SCSS, you can wrap your *pseudo-global* <sup>[1]</sup> styles like this:

```
.root :global {
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Now wrap your component/page in a `div` and set the class as `styles.root` on that element. Then, on all the child elements you can directly set `className="foo"`.

```js
import styles from "../styles/index.module.scss";

const IndexPage = () => (
  <div className={styles.root}>
    <div className="foo">This text should be red!</div>
  </div>
);

export default IndexPage;
```

Note that, you need to consider issues regarding specificity after this method, also this doesn't directly work with animations, you need to separate the `keyframes` and then make them global.

[Demo Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bose-fwx27)

---

[1]: This method doesn't make the styles truly global as the styles are still scoped. The class `foo` will work only when some parent has `styles.root` as class. This is preferrable only if you didn't intend to use your `:global(.selector)` from other components, and were using them just because you wanted to manipulate the class names using JS without the styles object.

If you want these to be truly global, add `styles.root` to `document.documentElement` in an `useEffect` hook like this:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/index.module.scss";

const IndexPage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.add(styles.root);
    return () => {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove(styles.root);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="foo">
      This text should be red, even if you put it in another component until the
      page is same. If you want it across pages inject it in _app or _document.
    </div>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

[Demo Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cherry-y5s11)

PS: Injecting class to `html` in `_app` or `_document` is **not** exactly same as using a [global stylesheet](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet), as it may happen that you have multi-page application, then only the CSS of the components on a particular page will be requested because of automatic CSS code-splitting done by Next.js. If that's not the case and all your pages share same CSS, then there is no need to complicate things, just go with the conventional method of importing styles in `_app`.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer. I have discussed the different approaches you wrote with my colleagues.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, the right writing is

```
.root:global {
   color:red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make a container, wrap it, and carry it out like follows:

```
import style from '../styles/style.module.css'
<div className={styles.container}>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

```cs
.container p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

And yes, you only need to include your tags and conditions in the CSS file if you have a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution to do global styles for CSS-Modules with Nextjs v14+ (Works in App-router & TurboPack) too.

add the class in the CSS file like this

```
:global(.my__global__class) {
  color: violet;
}
```

In the JSX use classname="" the normal classname not the CSS-Module one

```
// Wrong ❌ - Not-working

className={styles["my__global__class"]}

// Right ✅ Working

className="my__global__class"
```