# fix nextjs component level scss issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm converting normal react app to next js,

previously I just imported scss file using

```
import from '.componentName.scss'
```

But now I have to import using

```
import style from 'componentName.module.scss
```

therefore I have to change lot of code since this is previously completed project,
is there any way to configure nexjs that allow to import scss as before

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68531573/11613622

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it'll work but you can use https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config to create a custom webpack config in nextjs.  Along with that you can define a rule for styles.

```
...
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true
        }
      },
      'sass-loader',
    ],
    include: /\.s?css$/
  },
],
```

Using that I'm pretty sure you should be able to override the way it's searching for *.module files and including them in the css bundle.

Note don't just copy that code directly, make sure it'll actually work and configure it to your needs, it's just for frame of reference.

Comment: I have tried this one but lot of error with other dependencies